# MYSQL - Creating a Temporary Column that Indicates If Questions are Answered

Tags: mysql

Hi I'm currently developing a sort of quiz application. In "Discover" section I get popular and latest questions. But when I get them I should also check if question is already answered by current user or not.

Here are my tables:
questions: (media_id is primary key, player_id is creator of the question)

```
media_id - player_id - answer0 - answer1 - ...
```

answers: (media_id is primary key, player_id is the person who answers the question)

```
media_id - player_id - result - ...
```

This is how I get popular questions:

```
select * from questions where order by popularity_count
```

**EDIT:**
Let me show what I want to achieve by examples:

questions rows:

```
media_id - player_id - answer0 - answer1
0123456    abc123      bla       bla
6543210    hjk789      lor       ips
```

answers rows:

```
media_id - player_id - result
6543210    abc123      1
```

So when user "abc123" gets the popular questions results should be:

```
media_id - player_id - answer0 - answer1 - is_answered
0123456    abc123      bla       bla       0
6543210    hjk789      lor       ips       1
```

The problem is I need a temporary column in the result of query that indicates if question is replied by the current user or not. How can I achieve this?

I can find if question is already answered or not for popularity section by using two queries. First I get the popular questions then I simply check if question is answered or not for every questions which seems so ineffective way. How can I achieve this with only one query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem you are approaching this problem correctly as you have a non-normalized table structure.

You should have a separate table that contains the answers by row.

**questions** (id, media_id, player_id, question)

**answers** (id, media_id, player_id, question_id, answer)

This way you can `LEFT JOIN` `answers` to `questions` and easily see which questions are not answered like so:

```
SELECT q.question, a.answer
FROM question q
LEFT JOIN answers a ON a.question_id = q.id
  AND a.media_id = q.media_id
  AND a.player_id = q.player_id
```

### [See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12b17/2)

To add a column to your current query, you can append it to your `SELECT` and use a `CASE` statement to check whether it's been answered.

```
SELECT ..., 
    CASE
        WHEN answer0 IS NOT NULL
            THEN 'Yes'
        ELSE 'No'
    END AS 'Answered'
FROM ...
```

**Update**

Based on your update, it seems as though you are only `JOIN`ing on `player_id`. I believe you intend to `JOIN` on both `player_id` and `media_id`. See the difference between the [data you provided](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/630ce/2) and [what I think you intend it to be](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f4e36/1).

Comment: I can already see which questions are answered by a user with this query: `select * from questions where media_id in (select media_id where player_id = 'abc123')` My problem is how can I create a temporary column in the result of questions that indicates if question is answered by user or not.

Comment: player abc123 creates a question 0123456. Player hjk789 creates a question 6543210. Player abc123 answers only question 6543210 and its correct. Your solution seems that its not specific for a user only. When a user gets all questions it should check if question is answered by that user or not. I'm trying edit your solution but I stuck.

Comment: @YagizGurgul You need to re-evaluate your database design.

Comment: Based on your solutions I achieved what I want: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/630ce/7/0